# .htaccess for one url only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect **one** specific url, let's say /admin, from my domain to http, while the others all should redirect to https. Example:

```
Works:

http://example.com -> https://example.com
http://example.com/with-url -> https://example.com/with-url
https://example.com/admin -> http://example.com/admin

Does not work:

What I get (redirects from https to http, if under /admin): 
    https://example.com/admin/anything-below-here -> http://example.com/admin/anything-below-here

What I want (to stay on https):
    https://example.com/admin/anything-below-here -> https://example.com/admin/anything-below-here
```

This is what I got so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https:// for all except /admin    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for /admin URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# all the others
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp is greedy, so `/admin/something` matches `/admin`, hence the redirect from https to http once inside `admin`.

Try using `/admin[/]*$` instead to specify only `/admin` and `/admin/` should redirect to http, but not `/admin/something`

In order to check that the actual request URI ends after `admin`, you'll also need to switch to `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{THE_REQUEST}` which contains data AFTER the URI (for example, `HTTP/1.1`).

Try that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin[/]*$ [NC]
```

You don't need to change the other one check if `/admin` is not in `%{THE_REQUEST}` as it remains valid.

The complete code would then look like:

```
# force https:// for all except /admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin[/]*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for /admin URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin[/]*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# all the others
RewriteBase /                         
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I added that bit, but that does not work either - it let's me access /admin with both http and https now.

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin[/]*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin[/]*$ [NC]`

(I skipped the lines inbetween - this is not all I have in the .htaccess now).

Comment: Ah yeah, it's because you use %{THE_REQUEST} and there's stuff after the request uri... (HTTP/1.1 for example) so $ is not just after `admin`.

Comment: That did not do anything unfortunately, neither with or without a slash. It did not either redirect to http.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin[/]*$ [NC]` works on my local server

Comment: Make sure you empty your browser cache everytime you try something new as redirects *are* cached

Comment: Could you send the other lines too? Have you tested them as well?

Comment: I just did and it works as expected. First I had `/admin` redirected to https / `index.php?/admin` because I had no admin folder on my server. So the last rules works. Once I created an admin folder, `/admin`and `/admin/`are redirected to http if accessed from https but `/admin/test`is redirected to https if access from http.

Comment: And you leave all the other lines as they are, even the one with the "!"?

Comment: Now I get it why there's a difference between yours and mine. I have no admin folder either, that has to be handled with the index.php passing the parameter 'admin' to the script (I use Codeigniter for this). Then again, it should not redirect to index.php?/admin, but only serve its content.

Comment: Yes, it's weird I got redirected and not rewritten. It's a bit hard to test that again as I need to hack into an existing VPS to get the true https/http redirects going on. Since you stay on `/admin` (rewritten) you should be fine tho. I would suggest logging a bit more to see where your rules fail, check out https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog